# Posting from jQuery.ajax to a ASP.Net 5 Api Controller does not post integer parameter

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have the following api controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class WeightingDefinitionsApiController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult<WeightingDefinition>> PostWeightingDefinition(int id)
    {...
    }
}
```

When I call the `PostWeightingDefinition` from the .Net code it works.
Now I want to call this code from a `.cshtml` file using a `jquery.ajax`call:

```
var apiurl = "/api/WeightingDefinitionsApi/";
var data = { id: 13 };
$.ajax({
    url: apiurl,
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data:data,
    success: function (d) {
                 alert("Saved Successfully");
                },
    error: function (x,y,z) {
                 alert("Error please try again");
                }
            });
```

If I connect this code to a `button.click()` event the code in the api controller is called but the `id` parameter is zero instead of 13.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ajax request sends the id as form data payload. This happens because you didn't specify the `contentType` option for the `jQuery.ajax()` request and the default is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`. So you have to add `[FromForm]` attribute to the id parameter of your action:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<WeightingDefinition>>
    PostWeightingDefinition([FromForm]int id)
{
    ...
}
```

When you don't specify any attribute to the id parameter then `[FromQuery]` is inferred so you would have to pass the id as query parameter:

```js
var apiurl = "/api/WeightingDefinitionsApi?id=13";
```

Check the following links:

[ApiController attribute - Binding source parameter inference documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#binding-source-parameter-inference)

[`jQuery.ajax()` documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: Thanks! But I do not understand the why. What makes that this is a 'form data payload'? Other similar answers do not seem to include the `[FromForm]`attribute.

Comment: What makes it a 'form data payload' is that you didn't specify the `contentType` option for the `jQuery.ajax()` request and the default is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`

Comment: Also, if you don't specify any attribute to the id parameter then `[FromQuery]` is inferred so you could pass the id as query parameter: `var apiurl = "/api/WeightingDefinitionsApi?id=13";`